# Android - getView() - TextView null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I have a TextView reference in my custom Adapter's getView()'s method like this:

`final TextView favs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nofavs);`

This is fine, however, when I attempt to set its text immediately in the following line, I get a NullPointerException error:

```
final TextView favs = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favs);
favs.setText("3 favourites");
```

**EDIT:** LogCat

```
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at com.guide.Tab01_FavAdapter.getView(Tab01_FavAdapter.java:65)
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2461)
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
07-22 21:07:52.815: E/AndroidRuntime(31514):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
...
```

Comment: `favs.setText("3 favourites");` isn't the TextView called nofavs?

Comment: copy mistake. see edit

Comment: make sure that you convertView is a parent view of your text view. It seems that favs does not get defined

Comment: Show us the whole LogCat.

Comment: line 65: `favs.setText("3 favourites");`

Comment: What layout are you inflating for `convertView`? Can you post that layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud check if the convert view is null first and if its null inflate the view...

```
if(convertView == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
}
```

Read this [getView(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29)

Answer (score -1):

you should use `nofavs.setText("3 facourites")` because the variable's name is nofavs.